# Fatal error: Class 'Extendware_EWCore_Model_Autoload' not found

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm getting the below error while loading my Magento(Version 1.7) in local.I have checked the google and tried few things like setting permissions(chmod),Flushing cache etc, But it didn't workout well.

**Below is the error**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Extendware_EWCore_Model_Autoload' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/magento/app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php on line 14
```

Can anyone suggest me what to do on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check for the configuration file in the directory:
**app/etc/modules/**

Look out for a file which has registered probably Extendware_*.xml there might be more than one of them which will need to be disabled/removed.
Please clear cache to update the configuration.